# How use google maps autocomplete with filtering address by county and city?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, autocomplete

I am building a project and being asked to use the google maps autocomplete address API in this respect. So, in registration form I am getting the address of the user in three input fields as follows:

`Country : ______________`
`City : _________________`
`Address : ______________`

Suppose, user select `Canada` from the drop-down list of `Country`, then I would like `City` field to suggest autocomplete cities in the basses country and then simply again I would like address field to suggest autocomplete addresses on the basis of Selected `City`.

I am searching for this from this morning and still unable to find the correct and accurate solution/tutorial for my project. So please, someone help me in this respect so I can proceed with my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#set_search_area

You can bias the autocomplete results to favor an approximate location or area:

-
Set the bounds on creation of the Autocomplete object.

-
Change the bounds on an existing Autocomplete.

-
Set the bounds to the map's viewport.

-
Restrict the search to the bounds.

-
Restrict the search to a specific country.